# How do I extract a MAC address from a .txt file and place the address alone in another .txt

Tags: powershell

I am running powershell to create a text file "ipconfig.txt" and want extract the MAC address into another txt file "Output.txt" in order to not have to search for the MAC.

I have this code, but am not sure which variables I need to change in order for this script to run properly.

```
ipconfig /all >ipconfig.txt

Get-ChildItem "folder" -Filter *.txt | Select-String -Pattern '^%%' | Select -ExpandProperty line | Set-Content "Output.txt"
$log = get-content U:\ipconfig.txt
foreach ($line in $txt) { 
    if ($line -like "*C1-C1-C1-C1-C1-C1*") {
$line | out-file -FilePath "C:Output.txt" -Append
    }
}
```

Comment: what result do you get? how does that fail to match what you expect?

Comment: if you are running win10, take a look at the `Get-NetAdapter` cmdlet output. the MAC address will likely require you to pipe to `Select-Object -Property *` to see it. [*grin*] if you are on win7, that cmdlet is not included - you will need to use something like `Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_NetworkAdapter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the Get-WMIObject commandlet instead. This should produce the same results:

```
(Get-WmiObject win32_networkadapterconfiguration).macaddress | Out-File "macaddresses.txt"
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this looks like a promising route. I should have clarified in the original post, but I need to extract a MAC from an ethernet dongle specifically and don't care for the other relevant MACs, is there any way to filter such things?

Comment: Assuming the ethernet adapter is connected and has an IP, you could filter based on that. ```(Get-WmiObject win32_networkadapterconfiguration).macaddress | Where-Object{$_.IPAddress -ne $null} | Out-File "macaddresses.txt"```